# what happens if i sent bitcoin to a clubcoin address (address starts with a C)?

Tags: transactions, client, unconfirmed-transactions

what happens if i sent bitcoin to a clubcoin address (address starts with a C)? will i get refunded and get notified the transaction was invalid? please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Bitcoin addresses defined that start with a `C` (only P2PKH addresses which start with `1`, P2SH addresses which start with `3`, and P2WSH or P2WPKH addresses which start with `bc1`).

As a result, it is impossible to even create a transaction to such an address. There is nothing to refund of nofify - it's simply impossible to perform.

Comment: Depending the wallet, it's possible they simply converted the clubcoin address to the hex version and did the tx anyways - OP might be able to retrieve the coins by importing the private key for the clubcoin address into electrum or something, I've helped people in similar situations in the past

Comment: in ordee to send BTC, you need a BTC client. How would such software even know how to interpretba clubcoin addrss?

Comment: I've seen it happen with exchanges a few times - Some wallets/exchanges will accept any base58 address, since most coins just change the version byte, and interpret it as a regular btc p2pkh. The vertcoin webwallet accidentally burned a bunch of vtc this way when sending to segwit addresses some time ago. Sometimes, if you have the private key, you can get to the same address on the BTC chain (of course, it'll look different because of the version byte, but if the coin didn't change too much from BTC, you can still spend it)

Comment: But you're talking about altcoin software that did something crazy. In order to explain OP's behaviour, you need a Bitcoin wallet that somehow accepts a crazy address format. I don't think any wallet software out there is insane enough to act this way.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a btc wallet that's done that anytime recently off the top of my head. Just pointing out it's possible. If OP has a txid, the tx happened, so something somewhere messed up, and he might be able to get it back. If there's no txid, then the coins are still where they used to be

Comment: Thanks so much. I got freakingly worried as I accidentally sent 2600 worth usd to a clubcoin address! It was pending for a day (24hrs) and deducted my funds; and thank enough, funds are back! whew! thanks all.